# how to download a large file faster using telethon in telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api

i'm trying to do something that downloads a lot of file from a telegram channel
the code works well but it takes too long and above all that I have a slow internet connection
I have this code, I am downloading files that weigh 1gb but it takes a long time for an example to make the download faster?

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
import datetime
import os

def get_entity_data(entity_id, limit):
    entity = client.get_entity(entity_id)
    fecha = datetime.datetime.today()
    today = fecha.day
    yesterday = today - 1
    posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
                   peer=entity,
                   limit=limit,
                   offset_date=None,
                   offset_id=0,
                   max_id=0,
                   min_id=0,
                   add_offset=0,
                   hash=0))
    for post in posts.messages:
        post_day = post.date.day
        if post_day >= yesterday:
            if post.media is not None:
                try:
                    file_name = post.media.document.attributes[0].file_name
                except:
                    file_name = post.media.document.attributes[1].file_name
                directorio = os.getcwd()+'/descargas'
                if os.path.exists('descargas/'+file_name) == False:
                    print(file_name, 'Descargando...')
                    client.download_media(message=post, file=directorio)
                    print('Archivo descargado.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it by fewer `limit` and set `offset` and using multithreaded requests, maybe `pool` package helps you in this approach.
for example, the limit parameter set to 10 and there exists 1000 id which you want to get, so the offset should be `offset = [0, 10, 20, 30, ..., 1000]`
then:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
import datetime
import os
import pool

offsets = [0, 10, 20, 30, ..., 1000]
pool.map(get_entity_data, offsets)

def get_entity_data(entity_id={your_id}, limit=10, offset_id=0):
    your function
```

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with telegram APIs, but the map methods work as I edited the answer, If you can use a smaller limit and then download limited data per calling the method, and handle others by using offset, for example in first calling you get the data from [0, 10] id in parallel cal. you get [10,20].

Comment: thanks for your answer i did something different tell me if it's ok?   contador = 0                    
        while True:
        get_all_data(target_channel, contador)
        contador += 100
        if contador >= contador_total or contador_total <= 100:
            break

Comment: do you know any way how to download telegram file faster?